# Find text in Excel

Tags: excel, powershell

I am writing a script, to automate taking reports from various SQL databases, which is currently ran once a month manually. So far I have a working prototype that will read an SQL database and will parse the information into an Excel file, save it, and then email it to someone.

What I want to be able to do is have another Excel file called emails.xlsx. This file will have three columns: Emails(A), Server(B), Database(C). I want to be able to search the file for anything in column 2 that is the same and grab the emails from those rows and put them in to a var.

```
#Import Email Details
$emailPath = "C:\temp\emails.xlsx"
$sheetName = "emails"
$workBook1 = $excel.Workbooks.Open($emailPath)
$worksheet = $workBook1.sheets.Item($sheetName)

$cell = 1;

$CcCheck = $worksheet.Range.("A1").Text;

FOREACH($dbase in $worksheet.Range("C1").EntireColumn)
{
    DO{
        $CcCheck = $worksheet.Range("A$cell").Text;
        if($CcCheck -ne " ") {
            $data = $worksheet.Range("C$cell").Text;
            $server = $worksheet.Range("B$cell").Text;
            $Cc += ", $CcCheck";
            $cell++
       }
    } while($foreach.MoveNext() -eq $foreach.Current)
}
Write-Host " Loaded Server, $cell Emails and DB" -ForegroundColor "Green";
Write-Host "";
```

Comment: To be honest I'd import the data into PowerShell and work with it there rather than trying to reference and search it while it's in Excel. Check out [Import-Xls](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/17bcabe7-322a-43d3-9a27-f3f96618c74b) for getting the data into PowerShell from your workbook.

Comment: Is your current script doing something different than you expect it to? If so, what should it be doing?

Answer (score 0):

```
Import-Csv .\emails.csv -Header emails,server,database | Foreach-Object{

$dataSource = $_.server
$dataBase = $_.database
```

This fixed the problem by just referencing the headers after converting the excel file to a CSV.